# How to compare Object.keys for keys taken from an enum?

Tags: typescript, enums, switch-statement

I have an enum

```
enum Blockchain {
    Ethereum,
    Sepolia,
}
```

and an object:

```
const coinName = {
    [Ethereum]: 'ETH',
    [Sepolia]: 'SETH',
}
```

Now, I would like to call a function based on `Blockchain`:

```
const f = (_blockchain: Blockchain) => console.info(_blockchain)

// js file
Object.keys(coinName).map(_key => {
    switch(_key) {
        case Blockchain.Ethereum:
        case Blockchain.Sepolia: {
            f(_key)
        default:
            console.info('nothing')
    }
)
```

This prints `nothing` because `_key` is a string but the enum values are number by default.
How could I use switch case?

Answer (score 0):

You don't describe the background to the problem, but here's a solution that may help you move forward:

```
enum Blockchain {
  Ethereum,
  Sepolia,
  Dogecoin,
}

const coinName = {
  [Blockchain.Ethereum]: "ETH",
  [Blockchain.Sepolia]: "SETH",
  [Blockchain.Dogecoin]: "DOGE"
};

const f = (_blockchain: Blockchain) => {
  console.log(_blockchain);
};

// js file
Object.entries(coinName).map(([key, value]) => {
  switch (parseInt(key)) {
    case Blockchain.Ethereum:
    case Blockchain.Sepolia:
      f(value);
      break;
    default:
      console.info("nothing");
      break;
  }
});
```

There's Codepen here if you want to play around with the code yourself:
https://codepen.io/tkahn/pen/XWygeVN

Comment: Thanks! but what if the Blockchain enum comes from an external library?

Comment: I've edited the code example so the enum is unmodified (not a string enum). In the revised version the matching is done on the numeric key and the value is sent to the function.

Comment: So basically we need to rely on parseInt. I was wondering if there's a cleaner approach, maybe using a different definition for coinName

Comment: The parseInt is introduced because Object.entries return keys as strings.

Comment: I see, but I was wondering if there's another data structure that might be used to have the types automatically inferred